# Why does the missing word in this passage(only one word for each blank) have to be "would", and what's the logic of the sentence?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-meaning, past-habitual

> […I used to run with them, and had great fun; we used to gallop all together round and round the field as hard as we could go. Sometimes we had rather rough play, for they _____ frequently bite and kick as well as gallop.](http://www.best-childrens-books.com/black-beauty-book.html)

I googled for the original text and I got the answer that the missing word is "would". But I am not quite convinced of it as the only answer, and I think "might" is also acceptable here grammatically.

What's more, I find the sentence itself not very logical: I don't think "They(they are horses) would frequently bite and kick as well as gallop" can be the reason for "had rather rough play". The horses preferred to play in a violent way because they tended to bite and kick? I can hardly understand the logic here.

Can you help me?

Comment: I read a bit more. It's clear now that that *I* refers to a horse. This **[would](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/would)** (sense 4 "used for saying what someone used to do in the past") suggests what usually happened (as some people call this "habitual"). It goes well with *used to run*, and *used to gallop* in the same paragraph. So, "The ponies prefered to play in a violent way because they tended to bite and kick?" - Yes, that's right. (By the way, I think *colt* and *pony* do not have quite the same meaning.)

Comment: *"we had rather rough play"*: The word *"rather"* is meant to intensify the roughness of the *"play"* (a noun here). It's **not** meant to indicate preference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two questions:

### Filling in the blank

It's clear that you need a conjugated auxiliary verb to fill in the blank, since *bite*, *kick*, and *gallop* are all in their infinitive form rather than in a past tense form.

These sentences are talking about the habitual past.  Possible auxiliary verbs you could use for habitual past are [*used to* and *would*](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/Habitual-Past.htm).

*Used to* implies that the biting and kicking happened habitually in the past, but was no longer going on.  That's not the case here — the biting and kicking was concurrent with the rough play.  Therefore, even though *used to* appears twice in the previous sentence, it's not appropriate for filling in the blank.

*Might* is not quite right, as it clashes with *frequently*.  It expresses a possibility of something happening, and here we are talking not about a possibility, but something that *did* happen, repeatedly.

By elimination, *would* is the word of choice.

### Use of *for*

[*For* is being used as a conjunction](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/using-%E2%80%9Cfor%E2%80%9D-to-mean-%E2%80%9Cbecause%E2%80%9D), with a similar meaning to *because*.  You could interpret the sentence as

> Sometimes we played in a way that could be classified as rather rough, because they would frequently bite and kick as well as gallop.

Comment: How to understand "had rather"?

Comment: _Rather_ modifies _rough_. It is a hedge word that reduces the intensity of the roughness.

Comment: That's it! I misunderstood it as "would rather" before. "Play" is a noun here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @dennylv: Note that "had rather" *can* mean "would rather" -- just not in this case. (Sorry if you already realize this. I couldn't tell from your comment.)